# How to get minimum value from range date in DAX

Tags: dax

I need to get a calculated measure of the minimum date of a range of values, ie I have a fact table with a date and two measures. When I filter by range date, I need to get the second measure of the minimum date of that range, in the example, the measure 1 of 1st january, something like this:

https://db.tt/6jKBPRCr

The picture on the left is as I have the data in the fact table, data from the right as they should be when I filter from date (from 1st to 6 january). The measure 1 is added for a group, and measure 2 is the minimum value of the range of dates and must be repeated for each resulting record (highlighted).

I need the solution for PowerBI Desktop (DAX)

I would greatly appreciate your help with this.

Thank you for your time

Comment: How is `measure 2` being calculated?

Comment: The measure 2 is the minimum value from date range, in this case 400, and it repeats for each result row

Comment: I see the minimum value for `group 1` is 0 and 200 for `group 2`, in that date range. Try to explain better.

Comment: The measure 1 is a sum per group and the measure 2 generates a new measure. This new measure is the minimum value from measure 2 and it repeats for each agrupation for the measure 1.